# Angular Directive template inner partial $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We are working on a fancy-widget.  Here, we want to use ng-grid in our own directive.

```
<div fancy-widget >
    <div class=“fancy-part”>
        {{fancyImp}}
    </div>
    <ng-grid></ng-grid>  //ng-grid is part of angular-ui
</div>
```

Besides using `$compile(elem.children()[1])($scope)`  to compile ng-gird section in fancy-widget's link function, are there any other ways we could make it more smart?

The suggested template manipulate way did not quite please me. Since we already understand ng-gird, why we need to do it with a manual $compile here?

---

### Resolved with notes:

Just made my thought clear. I was actually under a 3rd party env in which we can only define directive and a loader to initialize these directive. ng-grid was lazy-loaded in the directive definition. since the lazyload returns a promise, so we can not expect when would the ng-grid module be ready. so we have to use $compile in the promise resolve. Here is the plnkr: (http://plnkr.co/edit/hyeIJx?p=info) –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ng-grid` is in your template then angularjs should automatically compile it as well. If you are adding it manually in the link function then there's really no other way other than to manually call `$compile`